# Devise Edit user error prohibited this user from being saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, devise

I keep getting the following error when i try to submit my edit user page. I am using devise and think something is wrong with my strong parameters. I have already ready through the devise docs etc but i have confused myself with this so some guidance would be most appreciated!

Thanks

```
   class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

   before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:name, :email, :password) }
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:name, :line1, :line2, :town, :county, :postcode)}
  end

 private
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    edit_user_registration_path(current_user) #basically whichever path you think meets your needs
  end
```

end

These are my routes

```
 Prefix Verb       URI Pattern                                Controller#Action
                 subscriptions POST       /subscriptions(.:format)                   subscriptions#create
              new_subscription GET        /subscriptions/new(.:format)               subscriptions#new
                  subscription GET        /subscriptions/:id(.:format)               subscriptions#show
                               DELETE     /subscriptions/:id(.:format)               subscriptions#destroy
                 content_fruit GET        /content/fruit(.:format)                   content#fruit
                   content_veg GET        /content/veg(.:format)                     content#veg
                   content_mix GET        /content/mix(.:format)                     content#mix
        new_admin_user_session GET        /admin/login(.:format)                     active_admin/devise/sessions#new
            admin_user_session POST       /admin/login(.:format)                     active_admin/devise/sessions#create
    destroy_admin_user_session DELETE|GET /admin/logout(.:format)                    active_admin/devise/sessions#destroy
           admin_user_password POST       /admin/password(.:format)                  active_admin/devise/passwords#create
       new_admin_user_password GET        /admin/password/new(.:format)              active_admin/devise/passwords#new
      edit_admin_user_password GET        /admin/password/edit(.:format)             active_admin/devise/passwords#edit
                               PATCH      /admin/password(.:format)                  active_admin/devise/passwords#update
                               PUT        /admin/password(.:format)                  active_admin/devise/passwords#update
                    admin_root GET        /admin(.:format)                           admin/dashboard#index
batch_action_admin_admin_users POST       /admin/admin_users/batch_action(.:format)  admin/admin_users#batch_action
             admin_admin_users GET        /admin/admin_users(.:format)               admin/admin_users#index
                               POST       /admin/admin_users(.:format)               admin/admin_users#create
          new_admin_admin_user GET        /admin/admin_users/new(.:format)           admin/admin_users#new
         edit_admin_admin_user GET        /admin/admin_users/:id/edit(.:format)      admin/admin_users#edit
              admin_admin_user GET        /admin/admin_users/:id(.:format)           admin/admin_users#show
                               PATCH      /admin/admin_users/:id(.:format)           admin/admin_users#update
                               PUT        /admin/admin_users/:id(.:format)           admin/admin_users#update
                               DELETE     /admin/admin_users/:id(.:format)           admin/admin_users#destroy
               admin_dashboard GET        /admin/dashboard(.:format)                 admin/dashboard#index
   batch_action_admin_products POST       /admin/products/batch_action(.:format)     admin/products#batch_action
                admin_products GET        /admin/products(.:format)                  admin/products#index
                               POST       /admin/products(.:format)                  admin/products#create
             new_admin_product GET        /admin/products/new(.:format)              admin/products#new
            edit_admin_product GET        /admin/products/:id/edit(.:format)         admin/products#edit
                 admin_product GET        /admin/products/:id(.:format)              admin/products#show
                               PATCH      /admin/products/:id(.:format)              admin/products#update
                               PUT        /admin/products/:id(.:format)              admin/products#update
                               DELETE     /admin/products/:id(.:format)              admin/products#destroy
                admin_comments GET        /admin/comments(.:format)                  admin/comments#index
                               POST       /admin/comments(.:format)                  admin/comments#create
                 admin_comment GET        /admin/comments/:id(.:format)              admin/comments#show
         admin_dashboard_index GET        /admin/dashboard/index(.:format)           admin/dashboard#index
              new_user_session GET        /users/sign_in(.:format)                   devise/sessions#new
                  user_session POST       /users/sign_in(.:format)                   devise/sessions#create
          destroy_user_session DELETE     /users/sign_out(.:format)                  devise/sessions#destroy
                 user_password POST       /users/password(.:format)                  devise/passwords#create
             new_user_password GET        /users/password/new(.:format)              devise/passwords#new
            edit_user_password GET        /users/password/edit(.:format)             devise/passwords#edit
                               PATCH      /users/password(.:format)                  devise/passwords#update
                               PUT        /users/password(.:format)                  devise/passwords#update
      cancel_user_registration GET        /users/cancel(.:format)                    devise/registrations#cancel
             user_registration POST       /users(.:format)                           devise/registrations#create
         new_user_registration GET        /users/sign_up(.:format)                   devise/registrations#new
        edit_user_registration GET        /users/edit(.:format)                      devise/registrations#edit
                               PATCH      /users(.:format)                           devise/registrations#update
                               PUT        /users(.:format)                           devise/registrations#update
                               DELETE     /users(.:format)                           devise/registrations#destroy
                product_orders POST       /products/:product_id/orders(.:format)     orders#create
             new_product_order GET        /products/:product_id/orders/new(.:format) orders#new
                      products GET        /products(.:format)                        products#index
                               POST       /products(.:format)                        products#create
                   new_product GET        /products/new(.:format)                    products#new
                  edit_product GET        /products/:id/edit(.:format)               products#edit
                       product GET        /products/:id(.:format)                    products#show
                               PATCH      /products/:id(.:format)                    products#update
                               PUT        /products/:id(.:format)                    products#update
                               DELETE     /products/:id(.:format)                    products#destroy
                    home_about GET        /home/about(.:format)                      home#about
                  home_contact GET        /home/contact(.:format)                    home#contact
                        seller GET        /seller(.:format)                          products#seller
                         sales GET        /sales(.:format)                           orders#sales
   static_pages_productlanding GET        /static_pages/productlanding(.:format)     static_pages#productlanding
                               GET        /content/veg(.:format)                     content#veg
                               GET        /content/fruit(.:format)                   content#fruit
                               GET        /content/mix(.:format)                     content#mix
             subscriptions_new GET        /subscriptions/new(.:format)               subscriptions#new
                          root GET        /                                          static_pages#home
                      contacts POST       /contacts(.:format)                        contact_us/contacts#create
                   new_contact GET        /contacts/new(.:format)                    contact_us/contacts#new
                    contact_us GET        /contact-us(.:format)                      contact_us/contacts#new
```

Comment: can you post your logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your going to want to generate the devise registration controller. Below is a link with instructions on how to do that.
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/Tool:-Generate-and-customize-controllers

You are going to throw this command into your terminal.

```
 bash <(curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/foohey/cdc/master/cdc.sh)
```

Once you have your registration controller generated you are going to want to put this code in it.

```
private

  def sign_up_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password)
  end

  def account_update_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :line1, :line2, :town, :county, :postcode)
  end
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, just to clarify what does this actually do? I installed the devise gem etc and sign up is working as is sign out but i am now recently having this problem with edit. I have edited the question so you can see my routes

Comment: I think so, i mean edit user registration....          edit_user_registration GET        /users/edit(.:format)                      devise/registrations#edit

Comment: Ok yeah so what my answer above is doing is defining the user account update params. So it is allowing you to update the new columns you added to your user table when you edit your user profile.

Comment: ah ok thanks so just to clarify i still have to create a registrations controller to do this?

Comment: i think what is confusing me is this command bash <(curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/foohey/cdc/master/cdc.sh) why this over rails generate registrations controller?

Comment: Devise has all of its controllers in the gem and you dont have access to them until you run that command... Once you run that command and follow the steps you will gain access to them. You can override them the defaults by using the code i posted in my answer.

Comment: updated with the following and resolved it devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:name, :line1, :line2, :town, :county, :postcode, :password, :password_confrimation, :current_password)}